# VBA Combo Box oDictionary Method Repeating Values

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, combobox

So I am trying to loop through a list of names and dates. The user types a name into a tb on the form and then when they click the dropdown it should populate with the dates that apply to that name. I am trying to use the oDictionary method to account for repeats. Yet everytime I click the dropdown they repopulate with double. So if they click the dropdown once then re click it there are two values for each date.

```
Private Sub cbCancelApptDate_DropButtonClick()
Dim NamePop As String
Dim NameRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Countcells As Integer



NamePop = tbNewApptName.Value

'Search All Appointments
    If Sheets("All Appointments").Range("C3") = "" Then
        Set NameRange = Sheets("All Appointments").Range("C2:C2")
    Else
        Set NameRange = Sheets("All Appointments").Range("C2", Sheets("All Appointments").Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    End If


Dim oDictionary As Object

Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Me.cbCancelApptDate
    For Each cell In NameRange
        If NamePop = cell.Value Then
            If oDictionary.exists(cell.Offset(, -2).Value) Then
                'Do Nothing
            Else
                oDictionary.Add cell.Offset(, -2).Value, 0
                .AddItem cell.Offset(, -2).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: at each click you are creating a new, empty dictionary, so it is normal that the list will double up because you restart over from scratch. try making your dictionary a "global", that is, declare it outside any sub.

Comment: Ohhh shoot, good thinking. I will try now.

Comment: @A.S.H It Worked fabulously, I publicked the set statement on Userform initialize. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @SanomaJean personal preference I would first fill the dictionary and then add all the items at once :`Me.cbCancelApptDate.List = oDictionary.Items`

Comment: @A.S.H Either you or the OP should post an answer so that the OP can accept it and close the question.

Comment: @ThomasInzina ok, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the dictionary save its content across multiple calls (clicks), it should be declared as a global.

```
' outside any sub:
Dim oDictionary As Object

'inside the sub:
if oDictionary Is Nothing Then Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```